# How to make Uibutton selected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` which remains selected when I select that button. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)cloudclick:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_cloud.png"];
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];
    [tmpButton setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
```

But it does not remain selected when I click the button. It changes the background but it does not remain as selected button.

Comment: Set Image for `UIControlStateNormal` only.

Comment: Why do `UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];` you already have the `UIButton` as in it is `sender`. It's not like you're making a copy of it are anything. I would remove this line and just use `sender`

Comment: I have created the button from Xib where thers is already a background image set now i want that when that button was selected it changes to another image. If I put the image in Xib button selected property in "state config" it does not show me the selected image

Comment: use `[tmpButton setSelected:YES];` for remain selected

Comment: @Ron That doesn't explain why you need the extra pointless line of code. You can just replace `tmpButton` with `sender`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to write one line after your code

```
- (IBAction)cloudclick:(UIButton *)sender {
    ...
    [tmpButton setSelected:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use this line of code

```
sender.selected=!sender.selected;
```

and set different image for diff states at the time alloc if you are making button from code otherwise set images from xib's.

Answer (score 3):

The various states: UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateSelected, and (UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted) are all actually distinct. If you want your shadowImage to apply both in the (only) highlighted state and in the highlighted+selected state, you must also set:

```
[button setBackgroundImage: bgImage forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected)]
```

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 5

```
sender.isSelected.toggle()
```